# Individual event listeners VS multiple VS multiple on() helper functions in JS

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

In Javascript, are there any relevant specific differences between handling delegated events with:

1. A single, collective event listener ?
2. Multiple individual event listeners ?
3. Multiple instances of an on() helper function ?

In particular, are there differences in:

1. Event propagation ?
2. Performance ?
3. The order in which multiple listeners / event handlers are fired ?

Example code:

1. Single, collective event listener

```
document.body.addEventListener(
  'click',
  function (event) {
    var el = event.target;
    
    if ( el.matches('[data-this]') {
      thisFunction(el);
    }
  
    if ( el.matches('[data-that]') {
      thatFunction(el);
    }  

  }
)
```

2. Multiple, individual event listeners

```
document.body.addEventListener(
  'click',
  function (event) {
    var el = event.target;
    
    if ( el.matches('[data-this]') {
      thisFunction(el);
    }

  }
)

document.body.addEventListener(
  'click',
  function (event) {
    var el = event.target;
    
    if ( el.matches('[data-that]') {
      thatFunction(el);
    }

  }
)
```

3. Multiple instances of an on() helper function

```
const on = function(selector, eventType, eventHandler) {
  document.body.addEventListener(
    eventType, 
    function(event) {
      const el = event.target;
    
      if (el.matches(selector)) {
        eventHandler(el);
      }

    }
  )
}

on("[data-this]", "click",  function(el) {
  thisFunction(el);
})

on("[data-that]", "click",  function(el) {
  thatFunction(el);
})
```

Comment: you are looking for a pattern called event delegation, which is actually the single listener case you mentioning. Libraries like React, that's how they handle events. Yes, there are differences about performances, plus other features/possibilities which only this approach allow. as far as i know, the basic implementation brings only benefits on the performance level, not on other topics. But again, with this pattern you can "unlock" features which are not possible with the other approaches

Comment: i instead think that 'on' will overwrite new handlers, addEventListener instead enqueues them